# Javascript retrieve hash after character

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-load

I am building an ajax website and it loads pages when I click on the navigation buttons just fine but the issues come when I reload the page. Once I reload the page, The page defaults back to loading `main.html` no matter what the url is. My hash is a little different, it looks like this `/#!/`. How can I retrieve the url and loose everything except the `/Path/`. For reference, this is what one of my urls looks like `http://mysite.com/#!/account/settings`. How do I get just the `account/settings` part of the url. Thanks a lot if I made any sense.

Comment: Could you format your question better? It's quite hard to read...

Comment: @elclanrs There you go, hope I am a little more specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a regular expression. I'm not the best at regex but this works:

```
var oldLoc = 'http://mysite.com/#!/account/settings',
    patt = /#!(.+)/,
    newLoc = oldLoc.match(patt)[1]; // This returns `/account/settings`
```

http://jsfiddle.net/elclanrs/WUL6a/

Answer (score 1):

Tried `window.location.hash.replace('#!/', '')`?

By the way, you should stop using hashbangs, and start using [HTML5 History API](http://html5demos.com/history) :)

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong but wouldn't that replace the hash? I'm not looking to get rid of the hash, just find out what the path is after the hash.

Comment: No, it returns the hash and removes the #!/ part of it. Why don't you try it and find out :)?

Comment: Ok thanks, sorry I couldn't try it, I was on my iPhone. Just tried it and it removes the #! but how do I remove the `http://mysite.com/` or  `http://www.mysite.com/`? Thanks

Comment: `window.location.hash` only returns the hash from the URL (so it doesn't return the domain/path). If you had a URL `http://mysite.com/#test`, `window.location.hash` would return `#test`. Then using `.replace()` you get rid of what you don't want.